# How we can filters an Observable by only allowing 2 distinct items through distinctuntilChange

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, functional-programming, rx-swift

Currently, I'm observing the `type` and `value ( int Int instead of Float )` of my slider and putting them in the tuple

```
durationSlider.rx_controlEvent(UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
              .subscribeNext { in                   
                    viewModel.callback.value = (type:SliderType.Duration, value:Int((self?.durationSlider.value)!))
               }
               .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
```

`callback` is `Variable` type in view model. To get the changes, I' doing

```
callback.asObservable()                        
        .subscribeNext {(sliderType, value) in
           print("value n is \(value)")        
         }
        .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
```

Since I emits the `valueChanged` in Int type instead of Float, I'm getting some same values

```
value is 13
value is 13 
value is 14
...........
```

Are there any ways to avoid getting the same values so that I only get the distinct value changed in Int for the slider. I'm not entirely sure if `distinctUntilChange()` can be used in this case.

All comments are welcomed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two possible solutions

1. Prevent duplicate when subscribing to callback

   ```
   callback.asObservable()
     .distinctUntilChanged { $0.1 == $1.1 }
     .subscribe(onNext: { _ in /* .. */ })
   ```

   This is good if you need to have subscribers in other parts of the code that will need to act on `.next` event that are not necessarily distincts.
2. Prevent duplicates before setting callback's `value`

   ```
   durationSlider.rx_controlEvent(UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
     .map { _ in Int(self!.durationSlider.value) }
     .distinctUntilChanged()
     .subscribeNext { value in
       viewModel.callback.value = (type:SliderType.Duration, value: value)
     }
   ```

   This is probably the solution you are looking for. Here, we first `map` each value changed event to the actual value, before filtering duplicates. This will ensure we do not set the same value twice in a row in callback. But this will not prevent another part of the code to set callback's value to the exact same, and in this case the subscription to callback could receive duplicates.

Comment: Hey @tomahh Do you know if there is a way to name params of a tuple in a distintUntilChanged call, as in this line? `.distinctUntilChanged { $0.1 == $1.1 }`